# Visual Studio 2019 does not properly convert UTF-8 strings to UTF-16 strings in source files without BOM

Tags: visual-studio, utf-8, visual-studio-2019

I have the following source file (encoded in UTF-8 without BOM, displayed fine in the Source Code Editor):

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBoxW(0, L"Umlaute ÄÖÜ, ", nullptr, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

When running the program, the special characters (Umlaute and Emoji) are messed up in the Message Box.

However, if I save the source file manually as "UTF-8 with BOM", Visual Studio will properly convert the string to UTF-16 and when running the program, the special characters are displayed in the Message Box. But it would be annoying to convert every single file to UTF-8 with BOM. (Also, I think GCC for example does not like BOM?)

Why is Visual Studio messing up my string, if there is no BOM in the source file? The *Auto-detect UTF-8 encoding without signature* option is already enabled.

I tested the same source with MinGW-w64 and don't have the issue, regardless if there is a BOM or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `/utf-8` compiler switch. The MS compiler assumes a legacy ANSI encoding (Windows-1252 on US and Western European versions of Windows) if no BOM is found in the source file.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the issue. It seems like a bug or at least unwanted behaviour.